# Maven, ActionBarSherlock v4 and Roboguice v2 - How do I get it to build?

Tags: android, maven, roboguice, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to build a project to uses both ActionBarSherlock v4 and Roboguice v2
(I like beeing of the bleeding edge :) ).

The problem is that ABS uses a slightly modified compatibility
library, that Roboguice needs. I got it working fine under Eclipse by
adding `actionbarsherlock-plugin-compat-lib-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT`,
`roboguice-2.0b3` and the `ActionBarSherlock` project.

Now the problem is that under Maven, I need to include the following
dependency because of Roboguice:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>android</groupId>
   <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
   <version>r3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

And I need to add the following dependency for ABS:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
   <artifactId>plugin-compat-lib</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

When I do a "mvn clean install", the following error occurs:

```
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/
support/v4/app/ActivityCompatHoneycomb;
```

because `ActivityCompatHoneycomb` is present in both dependency.

Any suggestions?

The full source code and build project is available at:
https://github.com/thierryd/adg-android

Comment: Perhaps dependency management will help you: either for `<artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>` or for `<artifactId>plugin-compat-lib</artifactId>` you need to add `<exclusions>` section. Look around how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @dma_k, it worked by adding the following "exclusion" tag and by removing the "compatibility-v4" dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
    <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: for correctness of the pom you might want to leave the dep for the compatibility library in but set it to be provided.. that should work too.

Comment: @ManfredMoser I tried setting it to provided and it didn't work. Can you submit a correct pom so that I could try it?